# Relative cell reference in formula doesn't change as expected when copied to a different cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml, copy-paste

I have a working IMPORTXML formula in Google Sheets that includes a relative cell reference. When I copy the formula to another cell, I expect the relative cell reference to update but it does not.

Here is my formula.

`=importxml("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=***AMZN&B3", "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[10]/b")`

If the formula above is in `O3`.  When I copy it down to `O4` I expect the relative reference to `B3` to update to `B4`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `AMZN&b3`  is a reference, then there is a syntax problem, unfortunately, the question looks to be unclear. Please [edit] the question to clarify what do you mean by `AMZN&b3`  and by `NAME&B4`

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour "Web Apps Tour"). Consider [registering your account](/users/login "Login") to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. [Registering](/users/login "Login") is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula contains a cell reference-as-string rather than a cell reference which is why it does not update.

It becomes a reference-as-string when it is enclosed in quotation marks **`"`**.

- **`B3`**    -  Reference
- **`"B3"`**  -  Reference-as-string

If you wanted a cell reference you would need to move **`B3`** outside the quotation marks:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://...ashx?t=***AMZN" & B3, "/html/body/...")
```